# Could anyone help check the derivation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm reading [this paper](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/papers/sne_final.pdf) and I'm trying to derive the gradient equation in (5) of the paper. But I couldn't get the right answer. My derivation is as follows. Could you help check it please?

[image: My derivation]